# Unable select Javafx combobox items programmatically which uses objects

Tags: javafx, combobox

In the JavaFx ComboBox which uses a class object list .I want to select items in the ComboBox programmatically using getSelectionModel().select(object or index). i am not getting the desired result Although the value is set but it is something like this main.dao.Company.Company.CompanyTableData@74541e7b.
The code is somewhat like this.

```
ComboBox<CompanyTableData> company = new ComboBox<>();
company.setItems(GetCompany.getCompanyTableData());//where Observable list is set..
```

GetCompany.getCompanyTableData() returns observablelist of CompanyTableData class.

The ComboBox Looks as follows.

[image]

The CompanyTableData Class is as.

```
public class CompanyTableData {
private SimpleStringProperty itemCompanyId;
private SimpleStringProperty itemCompanyName;
private SimpleStringProperty createBy;
private SimpleStringProperty createdOn;

public CompanyTableData(CompanyData companyData){
    this.itemCompanyId = new SimpleStringProperty(companyData.getItemCompanyId());
    this.itemCompanyName = new SimpleStringProperty(companyData.getItemCompanyName());
    this.createBy = new SimpleStringProperty(companyData.getCreatedBy());
    this.createdOn = new SimpleStringProperty(companyData.getCreatedOn());
}

public String getItemCompanyId() {
    return itemCompanyId.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemCompanyIdProperty() {
    return itemCompanyId;
}

public void setItemCompanyId(String itemCompanyId) {
    this.itemCompanyId.set(itemCompanyId);
}

public String getItemCompanyName() {
    return itemCompanyName.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty itemCompanyNameProperty() {
    return itemCompanyName;
}

public void setItemCompanyName(String itemCompanyName) {
    this.itemCompanyName.set(itemCompanyName);
}

public String getCreateBy() {
    return createBy.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty createByProperty() {
    return createBy;
}

public void setCreateBy(String createBy) {
    this.createBy.set(createBy);
}

public String getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty createdOnProperty() {
    return createdOn;
}

public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
    this.createdOn.set(createdOn);
}
```

}

The Cell Factory is set

```
company.setCellFactory(param -> new CompanyCell());
```

And the CompanyCell

```
public class CompanyCell extends ListCell<CompanyTableData> {
@Override
protected void updateItem(CompanyTableData item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty || item == null || item.getItemCompanyName() == null) {
        setText(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.getItemCompanyName());
    }
}
```

}

After all this when i try to set the items programmetically as

```
company.getSelectionModel().select(getSelectedCompanyIndex());
```

The getSelectedCompanyIndex() function is as follows.

```
public static CompanyTableData getSelectedCompanyIndex(){
    CompanyTableData c = null,i;
    Iterator<CompanyTableData> itr = GetCompany.getCompanyTableData().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()){
        i = itr.next();
        if (i.getItemCompanyName().equals(Element.getItemTableData().getCompany())){

            c = i;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

And the result i am getting is
[image]
And
[image]
At the end it should select a name or item in the list but it has set some type of object i think.

Now what should i do. Is there any type of string conversion required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buttonCell` used to display the item when the combobox popup is not shown is not automatically created using the `cellFactory`. You need to set this property too to use the same cell implementation:

```
company.setCellFactory(param -> new CompanyCell());
company.setButtonCell(new CompanyCell());
```